# Does any one know a nifty trick to edit a text file without vim, emacs, or nano just using BaSH?

Tags: bash, docker

For context, I am trying to create a docker image for a MySQL DB that I can log into without using a password. I am reading an [article](https://www.tecmint.com/connect-to-mysql-without-root-password/) on how to do that but it requires me to update the my.cnf in the container with the credentials I need to avoid needing a password.

One idea I had was to get the boilerplate version of the my.cnf file, put that in a normal text file, update it with the credentials I need, and copy that into the container. But I still don't know enough BASH commands to take text from one file and overwrite another. I am open to even just pointers on how I could do it with vanilla shell commands. Hopefully, this can help someone else from posting this question.

Here's what the my.cnf locals like originally

```
[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
secure-file-priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
user=mysql

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I need to update it to have something like this. This snippet has user and password line items.

```
[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
secure-file-priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
user=mysql

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[MySQL]
user=root
password=supersecret
```

Comment: Are you asking to be told about the existence of `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: I guess so. I will look up what those commands do

Comment: If someone doesn't beat me to it. I will post a nice answer for the next person.Thank you for the pointer @jeremysprofile

Comment: Or ... Are you asking to be told about the existence of [Here Documents](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)?

Comment: `ed` is very handy for editing files in shell scripts.

Comment: Those Here Documents are great I think I found what I need using awk. About to post the answer now. @SiKing

Comment: `sed` has an "edit file in-place" flag `-i`, but then you have to figure out how to do what you want in sed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the changes you want to make simply consist of adding to the end of the file, you can use an output redirect with `>>` to append to the file. Any of the following should work. Here's an example of using a shell "here-document":

```
cat >>.my.cnf <<'EOF'
[MySQL]
user=root
password=supersecret
EOF
```

Or you could use three separate `echo`s:

```
echo '[MySQL]' >>.my.cnf
echo 'user=root' >>.my.cnf
echo 'password=supersecret' >>.my.cnf
```

Or a single `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' '[MySQL]' 'user=root' 'password=supersecret' >>.my.cnf
```

Note that if your password contains a single-quote, it'll need somewhat more complex treatment in the `echo` or `printf` cases (because you can't include a single-quote in a single-quoted string).

Answer (score 0):

While in the appropriate directory I can run this.

```
awk '1; END {print "[mysql]"}' .my.cnf > tmp && mv tmp .my.cnf && awk '1; END {print "user=root"}' .my.cnf > tmp && mv tmp .my.cnf && awk '1; END {print "password=supersecret"}' .my.cnf > tmp && mv tmp .my.cnf
```

This was a great resource to learn how it works https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-scripting-using-awk/

Here's the basic pattern

```
awk '1; END {print "text to add"}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

for what ever file you specify it will add **text to add** to the bottom

Comment: if you're just looking to add 3 lines on the end of the file (per the latest edit of the question): `printf "[mysql]\nuser=root\npassword=supersecret\n" >> .my.cnf`; previous comments about `awk` and `sed` would still apply if the intention is to add lines somewhere in the 'middle' of the file (per the original requirements of the question)